# Code Change Never gets Deployed

Tags: deployment

I am having trouble with deploying code.

1. I have developed and deployed a farm soluton [version 1].
2. It works fine, with my custom button showing up.
3. I Retract the solution, clean solution and rebuild the solution.
4. When i deploy the code with minor changes [version 2]. No effect takes place. When i debug it brings up old code with minor changes missing. Basically it is still running version 1 of code.
5. Only way i can get version 2 of the code running is by restarting the server and deploying again.

Please let me know what am i missing.

Thank you

Sharepoint Newbie

Comment: Can you give more information on your solution ? Is is a feature, an application page, a central admin specific feature ? It would help us getting to your error !

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the timer service using this on a command prompt

net stop "Windows SharePoint Services Timer" 
net start "Windows SharePoint Services Timer"

If you developing a timer job it has a cached version of your dll so if you stop and start the service it will load fresh copy.

I guess you are doing an IISRESET/App Pool recycle after deploying right ? 
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by cleaning local IE content files, such as cookies, javascript files etc.

Comment: Probably you had javascript files and / or css files that were stucked to their old version.

Comment: As an editorial solution, could you mark your answer as "Correct" so that others may be able to find solutions to similar problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to double check the logs to be sure v2 deployed successfully. If so, then it may be a timer job issue (e.g. maybe the timer service hadn't finished deploying by the time you checked it).

Comment: 2007 or 2010 .Try building the solution  manually ( I know it is not the easiest route) but you have more control

Answer (score 0):

GAC deployments need IISReset

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a "Best practice" update on you solution, you can simply use the stsadm tool to upgrade your solution.  It will make the required restarts (Except if it is a timer job, you'll have to restart the SPTimerV3 (owstimer.exe) by hand.

Try the stsadm -o upgradesolution.